# Incorrect LIMIT and OFFSET Syntax in MariaDB Query

Tags: sql, mariadb

According to my MariaDB execution test, I have an error on my `offset` syntax, which is a part of a query that looks like this:

```
UPDATE
  clients
SET
  patient_firstname = Trim(patient_firstname),
  patient_lastname = Trim(patient_lastname)
WHERE
  patient_firstname Like '* *'
  OR patient_lastname Like '* *'
LIMIT
  10, 1
```

This isn't making sense to me, because according to the MariaDB documentation, this is the correct syntax:

```
LIMIT offset, row_count
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [**UPDATE** syntax](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/update/):

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference 
  [PARTITION (partition_list)]
  SET col1={expr1|DEFAULT} [,col2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
  [WHERE where_condition]
  [ORDER BY ...]
  [LIMIT row_count]
```

There is no `OFFSET`.  This is true in MySQL as well.

Your query has no `ORDER BY`, so `OFFSET` would have no meaning in that context.  You might as well leave it out.